# Need to download artifacts from MavenCentral if it is not available in the internal repository

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have following configurations on my `settings.xml` to get organization's internal artifacts.

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>internal-repository-1</id>
        <url>http://local.host/repository/internal/</url>
        <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Normally it has every artifacts to build internal projects. But I want to download some other artifacts from MavenCentral. Since I'm using above mirror configurations it will not check artifacts on MavenCentral.

I want to know is there any way to download artifacts from MavenCentral if it is not available in our internal repository by modifying `settings.xml`

I have already refer following questions and did not help.

[maven repository mirrors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4972288/maven-repository-mirrors)

[Can I add maven repositories in the command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71030/can-i-add-maven-repositories-in-the-command-line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your internal repo does not want to proxy to maven central repo you can disable requests for central to it like:

```
<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>internal-repository-1</id>
        <url>http://local.host/repository/internal/</url>
        <mirrorOf>*,!central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

Ensure you have central repository declared as the last one in your repositories list as maven 3 searches from top to bottom and you want central to be the fallback.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone have the same problem, putting following code block in to `settings.xml` also worked.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>profile-1</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>internal-repository-1</id>
                <url>http://local.host/repository/internal/</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>profile-1</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your internal repository is probably a Nexus or Artifactory. Just add MavenCentral as a proxy repository in your internal repository. Then you will be able to access everything from MavenCentral through the internal repository.

Comment: I don't have permission to done changes in the internal repository. Is there any way to do it using settings.xml?